# Saving different values with same title into different variables (BASH)

Tags: bash

Consider this output

```
General
Complete name                            : sample.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt  
File size                                : 37.3 MiB
Duration                                 : 9mn 56s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 525 Kbps
Writing application                      : Lavf52.73.0

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 9mn 56s
Bit rate                                 : 400 Kbps
Width                                    : 424 pixels
Height                                   : 240 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 24.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.164
Stream size                              : 29.9 MiB (80%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 98 r1629 9d1c441
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=64 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=90 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=400 / ratetol=10.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=10 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=768 / vbv_bufsize=3000 / ip_ratio=1.41 / aq=1:1.00 / nal_hrd=none
Language                                 : English

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 9mn 56s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 99.1 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 7.04 MiB (19%)
Language                                 : English
```

This is a sample output of a command which shows media information. This contains a Bitrate under the heading Video and another bitrate under the heading Audio. My aim is to store this two as different variables in BASH script.

Cant grep using line number since some files may have audio part and some did not have. So, is there any method to save this two values of same name into different variables?

Comment: I would use awk, /Audio/, /Video/,and  /Bit rate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the Video and Audio sections separately with sed, then extract the bitrates with another sed.
Let's assume the info is in a file.

```
VIDEO=`sed -n '/^Video$/,/^$/p' file`
AUDIO=`sed -n '/^Audio$/,/^$/p' file`
VBR=`echo $VIDEO | sed -nr 's/^Bit rate +: //p'`
ABR=`echo $AUDIO | sed -nr 's/^Bit rate +: //p'`
```

As to extracting the video and audio chapters:

- the `sed -n` option means no-print
- with `/.../,/.../` I define a starting regex and an ending regex
- `/^Audio$/` means the whole line contains just "Audio"
- `/^$/` means a blank line
- the `p` command prints the range defined above (overrides -n for the range)

Comment: That really worked :) But i want to learn the regex you used to fetch the video and audio part separately. Can you please explain it?

Comment: What about " sed -nr 's/^Bit rate +: (.+)$/\1/p'`" ?

Comment: Well, now you probably recognize the `sed -n '...p'` pattern. The `-r` (GNU-only) option uses a different (easier) regex engine, and then it's just a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If the output of `AUDIO` always comes after video, the following will work :

```
grep 'Bit rate[ ]*:' t|sed -n '1p'|cut -f2 -d':'|sed 's/^ //g'
```

for video and

```
grep 'Bit rate[ ]*:' t|sed -n '1p'|cut -f2 -d':'|sed 's/^ //g'
```

for Audio.

```
aman@a1:~$ VIDEO=$(grep 'Bit rate[ ]*:' t|sed -n '1p'|cut -f2 -d':'|sed 's/^ //g')
aman@a1:~$ AUDIO=$(grep 'Bit rate[ ]*:' t|sed -n '2p'|cut -f2 -d':'|sed 's/^ //g')
aman@a1:~$ echo $VIDEO 
400 Kbps
aman@a1:~$ echo $AUDIO 
99.1 Kbps
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sed to filter the video lines then grep the rate and store in video_bitrate. Do the same with audio.

EDIT: exactly the same method proposed simultaneously by Raul Andres using awk.